# could not access localhost:7050/chain when creating a fabric network

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I followed this tutorial to setup the fabric environment using java https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/Setup/JAVAChaincode.md.

I have also successfully set up the environment using `go` language which I completed after spending hours. and now I have decided to implement fabric network https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/Setup/Network-setup.md

I followed all the steps very carefully and I can `deploy` and `invoke` the transactions using CLI. I can even `query` the transactions using CLI but when I try to perform `REST` calls for the same purpose then I cannot access `localhost:7050` from my browser while it was working when I was deploying a normal `chaincode` without a network. is there any fix or am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: would you please share the details of your environment ? are you using docker inside vagrant ?

Comment: i am running ubuntu having vagrant installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind the port `7050` of the container to `0.0.0.0:7050` of your host machine, this can be achieved by providing `-p` flag (read here on [publishing a port](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#/publish-or-expose-port-p-expose)) while running `docker run` command for starting the container, so instead of,

```
docker run --rm -it -e CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://172.17.0.1:2375 -e CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG -e CORE_PEER_ID=vp0 -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true hyperledger/fabric-peer peer node start
```

use the following command to start the container,

```
docker run -p 0.0.0.0:7050:7050 --rm -it -e CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://172.17.0.1:2375 -e CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG -e CORE_PEER_ID=vp0 -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true hyperledger/fabric-peer peer node start
```

This should fix your problem.